# Laravel Object Access in Blade Template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent-relationship

I have queried in the blade template in a foreach loop like the way

```
@foreach ($employees as $employee)
 <td>{{ $employee->name }}</td>
 <td>
   @php  
     $project_info = \App\Models\Project::select('title')->find($employee->id);
     echo $project_info;
   @endphp 
 </td>
@endforeach
```

**Output**: `{"title":"Hull 21"}`     // when `echo $project_info;`

The problem is that I can not access to the "**title**" so that "**Hull 21**" is shown.
I have tried the following ways, but no luck.

```
// way 1
echo $project_info->title;
// way 2
echo $project_info['title'];
```

**Output way 1**

```
Trying to get property 'title' of non-object (View: /home/sajib/Desktop/emp/resources/views/backend/attendee/index.blade.php)
```

**Output way 2**

```
Trying to access array offset on value of type null (View: /home/sajib/Desktop/emp/resources/views/backend/attendee/index.blade.php)
```

If I debug with `dd($project_info->title)` then it gives output "**Hull 21**";

I need to echo/print the project title "**Hull 21**" for each **Employee**.

Comment: The error says that `$project_info ` is null. Fix that.

Comment: When I echo $project_info, it displays {"title":"Hull 21"}

Comment: You're getting a Project with an id of an employee? That doesn't seem correct. Anyway, is `title` a JSON field/column? Try `echo json_decode($project_info)->title;`

Comment: Try `$project_info = \App\Models\Project::find($employee->id)->value('title');` and access with `$project_info`

Comment: @kerbh0lz it does not work, Trying to get property 'title' of non-object

Comment: @Bennett  it shows an error, Call to a member function value() on null

Comment: @foreach ($employees as $employee) , here each employee got a project ? 
If one  of the employee has no project his project title might be null

Comment: Thank you guys. I did a mistake. Now fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

**There was a great Mistake I did.**

I should have searched the Project by Project ID, not Employee ID. Since each employee contains the `project_id` which is foreign key in the Employee Table.

**Database Table looks like this**

```
Project                 Employee
=========               ==========
id                      id
title                   name
                        phone
                        designation
                        project_id
```

So search query should be like this,

```
 \App\Models\Project::select('title')->find($employee->project_id);
```

Instead of,

```
\App\Models\Project::select('title')->find($employee->id);
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't make sense based on your described problem and what was being die-dumped. I'm having the same problem as you and can't find a resolution, it's really frustrating.